npm error code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL npm error Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*
The error is coming because the project is setup to use pnpm. But what I want is to display a suitable message to the user to let them know that they have to use pnpm instead of npm or yarn.
I have tried to add preinstall script but the issue is somehow the command npm i is running the workspace command on top and displaying this message:
*npm error code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL

npm error Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/lucifer/.npm/_logs/2024-10-20T16_20_28_424Z-debug-0.log*

Any way I can display a custom message to user?

You might have to leverage npm's lifecycle scripts to check if npm or yarn is being used and display an error message.
Please take some time to go with below:

Open your package.json.
Add a preinstall script that checks if pnpm is being used.

{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node check-pnpm.js"
  }
}


Create check-pnpm.js at the root.

const isPnpm = process.env.npm_config_user_agent && process.env.npm_config_user_agent.includes('pnpm');

if (!isPnpm) {
  console.error('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'ERROR: This project uses pnpm as the package manager. Please use pnpm instead of npm or yarn.');
  process.exit(1); // Exit with failure
}


If you run npm install or yarn install, the script will stop the installation process and display the custom error message.
If you run pnpm install, it will proceed as usual without any issues.


I did this earlier but the thing is that the npm is just returning the above msg for the workspace, it is not respecting anything such as preinstall.
